# Problems in proving the differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

I have to prove if this function is differentiable.

$$f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{\cos x-\cos y}{x-y} \iff x \neq y \\-\sin x \iff x=y \end{cases}$$

if $x \neq y$ it is continuous, but i want to see if it is continuous in x=y too.

i can rewrite f as 
$$ f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y} \iff x \neq y \\
g'(x)=g'(y) \iff x=y \end{cases}$$

and see that $lim_{xy \to xx} g(x,y)=g'(x)$. THus, it is continuous.
Also, the partial derivatives exist:
$$f_x(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{-\sin x(x-y)-\cos x+\cos y}{(x-y)^2} \\ -\cos(x) \end{cases}$$ 
$$f_y(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{\sin y(x-y)+\cos x-\cos y}{(x-y)^2} \\ 0 \end{cases}$$ 
If I proved that they are continuous, too, for the theorem of the total differential, the function would be differentiable. Still, I'm not sure this is the right way of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos x-\cos y=-2\sin\frac{x+y}2\,\sin\frac{x-y}2$ and $\operatorname {sinc}u=\frac{\sin u}{u}$ is a known analytical function. So $f(x,y)=-\sin\frac{x+y}2\operatorname {sinc}\frac{x-y}2$.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfectly OK way to do your work.

ALternatively, you might look at the function

$$
h(u, y) =  f(u+y, y).
$$

Writing that out, you get
$$
h(u, y) = f(u+y,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{\cos(u+y)-\cos(y)}{u} \iff u+y \neq y \\
-\sin(y) \iff u = 0 \end{cases}
$$

Which you can rewrite as 
$$
h(u, y) = f(u+y,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{\cos(u+y)-\cos(y)}{u} \iff u \neq 0 \\
-\sin(y) \iff u = 0 \end{cases}
$$

In these rotated coordinates, it might be a little easier to prove things.

Answer (score 0):

One has
$$f(x,y)=-\int_0^1\sin\bigl((1-t)y+t\,x\bigr)\ dt\qquad\forall\ (x,y)\in{\mathbb R}^2\ .$$
This shows that $f\in C^\infty({\mathbb R}^2)$.